# What do you call the menu in this image

Tags: ios

And how do you create that in swift ?[image]

Comment: I’m referring to the menu in the upper right hand corner

Comment: The menu, the three red line? Look for "Hamburger Menu + Swift". SWRevealsomething, etc.

Comment: Yes, I have never heard of hamburger menu and for those of you who think I didn't search I tried googling it, etc.  Couldn't find the answer so I came here. Thanks for the help Larme.... mucho appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I agree Beth, sometimes users are a little overly demanding on here; that said, it would have been helpful if you had listed the sources you tried to determine what the menu was.  I know its not easy when working off a screen example.